# wxProgressDialog crashes with wxWidgets 3.1.3

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have updated to latest wxWidgets 3.1.3 (Windows) recently and now stumble upon a strange problem with an application, that worked properly before. The problem happens when creating a wxProgressDialog. A call to

```
new wxProgressDialog(...
```

crashes in progdlg.cpp at line 1114:

```
HRESULT hr = taskDialogIndirect(&tdc, &msAns, NULL, NULL);
```

It seems (but I'm not sure yet), this happens when the wxProgressDialog is created out of an event handler. As said, the application was not changed and worked properly until now. So I would assume somethign has changed in 3.1.3. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: coud you try to reproduce it in a dialogs sample? Also - what version of Windows are testing on? Which variable is NULL at the time of crash?

Comment: There is really no reason for it to crash at this line, something might be wrong with your (re)build. Also consider checking the `dialogs` sample which shows the progress dialog in action. If it doesn't crash for you, try to find the difference between what it does and what your code does.

Comment: The point is, not all of my wxProgressDialogs are doing this, just a few ones like the one mentioned here. The other thing is: the application is unchanged, all I have done is updating to latest wxWidgets. So may be there is something wrong with my code but it seems to be caused by a modification in wxWidgets. So was there something changed in that area?

Comment: @VZ OK, there MUST have something been changed in latest version. I tried with an other application, nothing was changed there except the update of wxWidgets and now I repeatedly get this assert when calling wxAboutBox() out of a plain and stupid wxCommandEvent-handler  https://i.ibb.co/LNDf5CS/about.png Fun fact: the assert message box also pops up in release-build with preprocessor switch wxDEBUG_LEVEL=0

Comment: The assert looks very strange too, it looks like this _is_ called from the main thread (you can easily check this if you break into a debugger). But the real red flag is that you get asserts when you think you built with `wxDEBUG_LEVEL=0`: this is just impossible. I.e. you absolutely are using a different version of wxWidgets or a version built with different `wx/setup.h` or some other mismatch. Please double check your build environment and rebuild everything from scratch.

Comment: @VZ: I'll check the release build thingy. But it is definitely not done out of the main thread, I can see it in debugger: select menu item -> end up in CommandEvent handler function -> call wxAboutBox() -> get this assert. As said, exactly the same code works fine with 3.0.

Comment: I'm completely lost. Menu selection event should only be processed in the main thread. Are you running the event loop in another thread?